# FirebaseCrashlytics: Send to Reports Endpoint for non-native reports disabled

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics-android

I connected FirebaseCrashlytics as described [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=android) for Android.
Then I tried to send a test exception and got these lines in the FirebaseCrashlitycs log:

```
...
FirebaseCrashlytics: Attempting to send crash report at time of crash...
FirebaseCrashlytics: Send to Reports Endpoint for non-native reports disabled. Removing Reports Uploader report.
...
```

No crash events appeared in the FirebaseConsole during 2 hours. What does it mean - "Send to Reports Endpoint for non-native reports disabled.", how to fix that?

Comment: Have you found any solution for this?

Answer (score 4):

The problem was in AndroidStudio cache, "invalidate cache & restart" got helped me.

Comment: I think there was a cached old version of google.json file. I've added a new version, but that wasn't worked, then i tried to execute  the "invalidate cache & restart" operation.

Comment: I see,w it worked for me too when I "invalidate cache & restart" just wasn't sure why that should affect. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 3):

Are you using android emulator? I'm facing this issue when use emulator created on the *AVD Manager* of Android Studio - *Pixel 2 API 22 Lollipop*. When i testing on real device - *Android 10 api 29* - works fine.

I facing issues for send crash to firebase crashlytics for a week, (i changed version of all dependencies and sdk many times) but today, after contact support and try force crash sometimes( the only thing that i made of diferent, suggested by them, was activate debugger mode in logcat ) the project magically sended a crash to console.

EDIT: The sugestion of @Maxim Firsoff works fine for me on another project too (in android emulator).

Answer (score 0):

The message "Send to Reports Endpoint for non-native reports disabled." is irrelevant to seeing crashes show up in the Firebase console.

Initially, none of my crashes were appearing there.  I too thought the message might be a clue.
Not so.  I continued to get the message even after my app's crashes started being logged.

Unfortunately, I can't say exactly what fixed the problem.  It may have been deleting the Android project's build folder or invalidating cache and restarting.  It just started working after hours of trying many things.