# Crashlytics Console not showing crashes

Tags: flutter, crashlytics

I am trying to implement Crashlytics in flutter by using this blog post(https://medium.com/flutter-community/how-to-keep-track-of-bugs-by-integrating-firebase-crashlytics-in-flutter-app-6c406e346d4a) . I am using sample code on the flutter pub.dev page. (https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_crashlytics/example)
I have configured build.gradle both on application and module level as mentioned in the post. For some reason I cannot see the crash on the firebase console. Below is the adb log from launching app, adding log, crahing app and relaunching the app. It says FirebaseApp initialization is successful but not posting a crash to the console.

```
    10-25 18:12:05.713  8845  9433 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Received Analytics message: 3 Bundle[{params=Bundle[{_o=auto, _et=6276397, _sc=MainActivity, _si=922543423047567062}], name=_e, timestampInMillis=1603663925446}]
10-25 18:12:07.740  8845  9433 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Received Analytics message: 3 Bundle[{params=Bundle[{_o=auto}], name=_ab, timestampInMillis=1603663925626}]
10-25 18:12:17.011  9448  9448 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Crashlytics automatic data collection ENABLED by API.
10-25 18:12:17.012  9448  9448 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Firebase Analytics is available.
10-25 18:12:17.013  9448  9448 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Firebase Analytics listener registered successfully.
10-25 18:12:17.037  9448  9448 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Reading cached settings...
10-25 18:12:17.065  9448  9448 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Loaded cached settings: {"settings_version":3,"cache_duration":86400,"features":{"collect_logged_exceptions":true,"collect_reports":true,"collect_analytics":false,"prompt_enabled":false,"push_enabled":false,"firebase_crashlytics_enabled":false},"app":{"status":"activated","update_required":false,"report_upload_variant":2,"native_report_upload_variant":2},"fabric":{"org_id":"5f94872f42fba669b0be7e64","bundle_id":"ca.mervice.flutterfirebase"},"expires_at":1603735927625}
10-25 18:12:17.065  9448  9448 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Returning cached settings.
10-25 18:12:17.068  9448  9448 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Mapping file ID is: 00000000000000000000000000000000
10-25 18:12:17.068  9448  9448 I FirebaseCrashlytics: Initializing Crashlytics 17.2.2
10-25 18:12:17.069  9448  9448 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Installer package name is: null
10-25 18:12:17.118  9448  9448 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Exception handling initialization successful
10-25 18:12:17.128  9448  9470 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Found matching FID, using Crashlytics IID: 65040d6e57974e58b2e345356485e7b6
10-25 18:12:17.128  9448  9470 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Opening a new session with ID 5F95F8410077-0001-24E8-25C71397F0E6    
10-25 18:12:17.179  9448  9470 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Initialization marker file created.
10-25 18:12:17.180  9448  9470 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Registered Firebase Analytics event receiver for breadcrumbs
10-25 18:12:17.181  9448  9470 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Finalizing previously open sessions.
10-25 18:12:17.187  9448  9470 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Closing open sessions.
10-25 18:12:17.187  9448  9470 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Closing session: 5F95DFB002D6-0001-228D-25C71397F0E6
10-25 18:12:17.187  9448  9470 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Collecting session parts for ID 5F95DFB002D6-0001-228D-25C71397F0E6
10-25 18:12:17.188  9448  9470 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Session 5F95DFB002D6-0001-228D-25C71397F0E6 has fatal exception: false
10-25 18:12:17.191  9448  9470 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Session 5F95DFB002D6-0001-228D-25C71397F0E6 has non-fatal exceptions: false
10-25 18:12:17.191  9448  9470 D FirebaseCrashlytics: No events present for session ID 5F95DFB002D6-0001-228D-25C71397F0E6
10-25 18:12:17.192  9448  9470 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Removing session part files for ID 5F95DFB002D6-0001-228D-25C71397F0E6
10-25 18:12:17.197  9448  9470 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Finalizing report for session 5F95DFB002D60001228D25C71397F0E6       
10-25 18:12:17.197  9448  9470 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Session 5F95DFB002D60001228D25C71397F0E6 has no events.
10-25 18:12:17.198  9448  9470 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Closed all previously open sessions
10-25 18:12:17.205  9448  9470 D FirebaseCrashlytics: No reports are available.
10-25 18:12:17.220  9448  9470 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Initialization marker file removed: true
10-25 18:12:18.177  9448  9472 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Received Analytics message: 3 Bundle[{params=Bundle[{_o=auto, _sc=MainActivity, _si=634204832436112801}], name=_vs, timestampInMillis=1603663937993}]
10-25 18:12:22.065  9448  9494 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Crashlytics automatic data collection ENABLED by API.
10-25 18:12:41.141  9448  9448 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Crashlytics is handling uncaught exception "io.flutter.plugins.firebase.crashlytics.FirebaseCrashlyticsTestCrash: This is a test crash caused by calling .crash() in Dart." from thread main    
10-25 18:12:41.150  9448  9470 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Persisting fatal event for session 5F95F8410077000124E825C71397F0E6
10-25 18:12:41.311  9448  9470 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Closing open sessions.
10-25 18:12:41.311  9448  9470 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Closing session: 5F95F8410077-0001-24E8-25C71397F0E6
10-25 18:12:41.311  9448  9470 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Collecting session parts for ID 5F95F8410077-0001-24E8-25C71397F0E6  
10-25 18:12:41.312  9448  9470 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Session 5F95F8410077-0001-24E8-25C71397F0E6 has fatal exception: true10-25 18:12:41.312  9448  9470 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Session 5F95F8410077-0001-24E8-25C71397F0E6 has non-fatal exceptions: false
10-25 18:12:41.313  9448  9470 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Collecting SessionStart data for session ID 5F95F8410077-0001-24E8-25C71397F0E6
10-25 18:12:41.314  9448  9470 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Collecting SessionUser data for session ID 5F95F8410077-0001-24E8-25C71397F0E6
10-25 18:12:41.315  9448  9470 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Collecting SessionApp data for session ID 5F95F8410077-0001-24E8-25C71397F0E6
10-25 18:12:41.315  9448  9470 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Collecting SessionOS data for session ID 5F95F8410077-0001-24E8-25C71397F0E6
10-25 18:12:41.316  9448  9470 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Collecting SessionDevice data for session ID 5F95F8410077-0001-24E8-25C71397F0E6
10-25 18:12:41.317  9448  9470 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Removing session part files for ID 5F95F8410077-0001-24E8-25C71397F0E6
10-25 18:12:41.320  9448  9470 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Finalizing report for session 5F95F8410077000124E825C71397F0E6       
10-25 18:12:41.387  9448  9470 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Opening a new session with ID 5F95F8590181-0002-24E8-25C71397F0E6    
10-25 18:12:41.405  9448  9470 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Crashlytics automatic data collection ENABLED by API.
10-25 18:12:41.417  9448  9500 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Logging Crashlytics event to Firebase
10-25 18:12:41.420  9448  9500 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Awaiting app exception callback from FA...
10-25 18:12:41.555  9448  9472 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Received Analytics message: 3 Bundle[{params=Bundle[{_o=clx, _r=1, _et=23518, _sc=MainActivity, _si=634204832436112801, timestamp=1603663961142, fatal=1}], name=_ae, timestampInMillis=1603663961419}]
10-25 18:12:41.561  9448  9500 D FirebaseCrashlytics: App exception callback received from FA listener.
10-25 18:12:41.589  9448  9470 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Crashlytics report successfully enqueued to DataTransport: 5F95F8410077000124E825C71397F0E6
10-25 18:12:41.601  9448  9448 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Crashlytics completed exception processing. Invoking default exception handler.
10-25 18:12:41.602  9448  9470 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Attempting to send crash report at time of crash...
10-25 18:12:41.605  9448  9470 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Send to Reports Endpoint disabled. Removing Reports Endpoint report. 
10-25 18:12:41.606  9448  9470 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Removing report at /data/user/0/ca.mervice.flutterfirebase/files/.com.google.firebase.crashlytics/fatal-sessions/5F95F8410077-0001-24E8-25C71397F0E6.cls
10-25 18:12:41.773  9448  9472 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Received Analytics message: 3 Bundle[{params=Bundle[{_o=auto, _et=23625, _fr=1, _sc=MainActivity, _si=634204832436112801}], name=_e, timestampInMillis=1603663961594}]
10-25 18:12:48.078  9505  9505 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Crashlytics automatic data collection ENABLED by API.
10-25 18:12:48.081  9505  9505 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Firebase Analytics is available.
10-25 18:12:48.101  9505  9505 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Firebase Analytics listener registered successfully.
10-25 18:12:48.124  9505  9505 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Reading cached settings...
10-25 18:12:48.150  9505  9505 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Loaded cached settings: {"settings_version":3,"cache_duration":86400,"features":{"collect_logged_exceptions":true,"collect_reports":true,"collect_analytics":false,"prompt_enabled":false,"push_enabled":false,"firebase_crashlytics_enabled":false},"app":{"status":"activated","update_required":false,"report_upload_variant":2,"native_report_upload_variant":2},"fabric":{"org_id":"5f94872f42fba669b0be7e64","bundle_id":"ca.mervice.flutterfirebase"},"expires_at":1603735927625}
10-25 18:12:48.151  9505  9505 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Returning cached settings.
10-25 18:12:48.170  9505  9505 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Mapping file ID is: 00000000000000000000000000000000
10-25 18:12:48.171  9505  9505 I FirebaseCrashlytics: Initializing Crashlytics 17.2.2
10-25 18:12:48.180  9505  9505 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Installer package name is: null
10-25 18:12:48.329  9505  9528 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Found previous crash marker.
10-25 18:12:48.355  9505  9505 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Exception handling initialization successful
10-25 18:12:48.458  9505  9528 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Found matching FID, using Crashlytics IID: 65040d6e57974e58b2e345356485e7b6
10-25 18:12:48.469  9505  9528 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Opening a new session with ID 5F95F8600163-0001-2521-25C71397F0E6
10-25 18:12:48.618  9505  9528 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Initialization marker file created.
10-25 18:12:48.626  9505  9528 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Registered Firebase Analytics event receiver for breadcrumbs
10-25 18:12:48.626  9505  9528 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Finalizing previously open sessions.
10-25 18:12:48.704  9505  9528 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Closing open sessions.
10-25 18:12:48.705  9505  9528 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Closing session: 5F95F8590181-0002-24E8-25C71397F0E6
10-25 18:12:48.705  9505  9528 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Collecting session parts for ID 5F95F8590181-0002-24E8-25C71397F0E6
10-25 18:12:48.706  9505  9528 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Session 5F95F8590181-0002-24E8-25C71397F0E6 has fatal exception: false
10-25 18:12:48.707  9505  9528 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Session 5F95F8590181-0002-24E8-25C71397F0E6 has non-fatal exceptions: false
10-25 18:12:48.707  9505  9528 D FirebaseCrashlytics: No events present for session ID 5F95F8590181-0002-24E8-25C71397F0E6
10-25 18:12:48.710  9505  9528 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Removing session part files for ID 5F95F8590181-0002-24E8-25C71397F0E6
10-25 18:12:48.730  9505  9528 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Finalizing report for session 5F95F8590181000224E825C71397F0E6       
10-25 18:12:48.733  9505  9528 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Session 5F95F8590181000224E825C71397F0E6 has no events.
10-25 18:12:48.736  9505  9528 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Closed all previously open sessions
10-25 18:12:48.744  9505  9528 D FirebaseCrashlytics: No reports are available.
10-25 18:12:48.765  9505  9528 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Initialization marker file removed: true
10-25 18:12:49.486  9505  9530 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Received Analytics message: 3 Bundle[{params=Bundle[{_o=auto, _sc=MainActivity, _si=-763624855939962507}], name=_vs, timestampInMillis=1603663969341}]
10-25 18:12:53.098  9505  9553 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Crashlytics automatic data collection ENABLED by API.
```

Comment: [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54434528/crashlytics-not-appear-crash-in-dashboard/64550385#64550385) in a similar/duplicated [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54434528/crashlytics-not-appear-crash-in-dashboard/64550385)

Answer (score 1):

At ...

```
18:12:41.417 - Logging Crashlytics event to Firebase
```

it says Crashlytics triggers an upload, but at...

```
18:12:41.605 - Send to Reports Endpoint disabled. Removing Reports Endpoint report.
```

you can see that it was not successful so it can not appear in the Firebase console.

I found a similiar error: [FirebaseCrashlytics: Send to Reports Endpoint for non-native reports disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63736216/firebasecrashlytics-send-to-reports-endpoint-for-non-native-reports-disabled)

Maybe that solution (just cache invalidating and restarting of your IDE) also helps you.